# How to bind property of dynamically created components of a user control to another component?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatrigger

I have a user control which creates a set of radio buttons based on a list. The radio buttons are created using data template.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <SelectableItem:SelectableItem x:Key="vm"></SelectableItem:SelectableItem>
        <src:RadioButtonCheckedConverter x:Key="RadioButtonCheckedConverter" />
        <CollectionViewSource
                Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=ItemDescription}"
                x:Key="ListingDataView" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeaderTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="RadioGroup" AutomationProperties.Name="RadioGroup" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton
                                 GroupName="{Binding Path=ItemType}"
                                 Content="{Binding Path=ItemDescription}"
                                 FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{DynamicResource CustomRadioButton}" Margin="20,0" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Tag="{Binding Path=ItemDescription, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I use this in a window where I need to change the visibility of a component (stack panel) based on the selected radio button.

```
<uc:CommonRadioButtonGroup x:Name="SelectionButtonsGroup" ></uc:CommonRadioButtonGroup>
```

I am trying to change the visibility using style triggers.

```
<Style x:Key="spStyle" TargetType="StackPanel" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Local:EngineModes.PresentMode}}" Value="Stop">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Local:EngineModes.PresentMode}}" Value="Wait">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Local:EngineModes.PresentMode}}" Value="Go">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>                
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

I cannot figure out a way to implement the viewmodel for this one. I tried this one:

```
public class EngineModes : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static List<SelectableItem> Modes { get; set; } = new List<SelectableItem>();
                public static string PresentMode { get; set; }

  
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyInfo)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyInfo));
            }
            ));
        }
    }
```

where "Modes" are the options of the radio button. But it simply does not work.

Ultimately, on selecting a mode using radio button, the visibility of the stack panel must be modified.
Please comment on the correctness of the code.

**Edit:**
Here is the ItemSource for the user control added in codebehind:

```
 SelectionButtonsGroup.RadioGroup.ItemsSource = EngineModes.Modes;

        this.DataContext = EngineModes.PresentMode;
```

Comment: What are you using as the ItemsSource for your ItemsControl?

Comment: Please check the Edit for how I have given the ItemSource. It is a static list of type "SelectableItems".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the style as

```
<Style x:Key="sprecStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">            
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource engineModes}, Path=PresentMode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Stop">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource engineModes}, Path=PresentMode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Wait">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource engineModes}, Path=PresentMode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Go">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>  
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And added a separate notified event for static property change:

```
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged
     = delegate { };
    public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

and called it where the engine mode is updated.

```
EngineModes.NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("PresentMode");
```

And voila! It worked.